# Flutter :How to change the size of text from specific text in a list of strings?

Tags: string, flutter

Hello I want to show how I will change the text style of this in the list of strings
١۝۷ع in last line

static final List Fatiha = [
'اَلْحَمْدُ لِلّٰهِ رَبِّ الْعٰلَمِیْنَۙ۝۱',
'الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِیْمِۙ۝۲',
'مٰلِكِ یَوْمِ الدِّیْنِؕ۝۳',
'اِیَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَ اِیَّاكَ نَسْتَعِیْنُؕ۝۴',
'اِهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِیْمَۙ۝۵',
'صِرَاطَ الَّذِیْنَ اَنْعَمْتَ عَلَیْهِمْ ۙ۬ۦ',
'غَیْرِ الْمَغْضُوْبِ عَلَیْهِمْ وَ لَا الضَّآلِّیْنَ۠١۝۷ع'
];

Comment: The `String` has no style, `Text` has. Would you mind sharing your code implementation ?

Comment: is there any way to call a function in  list  of strings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Change Style In the UI, Then you have to Show Strings In the Text("String",TexStyle(fontSize,FontFamily,,etc))  But If you want to See in the Code Editor for better Visibility then you have to  Adjust The Code Editor Zoom Level using Control +,

Comment: can i send you an image of my ui?

Comment: Yes But  The Point is  You need to Use ListView if You wan to Display Data as a Table, Inside a Text Widget

Answer (score 0):

```
Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            style: style1,
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text:
                    $firstPart',
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: '$partYouWantDifferentStyle',
                style: style2,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: '$lastPart',
              )
            ],
          ),
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        )
```